# Levenshtein-distance algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

```
def worddistance(source, target):
    ''' Return the Levenshtein  distance between 2 strings '''  

    if len(source) > len(target):
        source, target = target, source
    #Now target becomes the larger string, if it is 0, surely len(source) is 0?
    if len(target) == 0: 
        return len(source)

  ### Continue on to calculate distance.
```

Isn't it the same as saying if both the parameters are the same, return 0?

I am not exactly sure what this part of the function is trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, the code returns `0` if both are length 0.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not sure if it does anything else. If not, I would just simplicity it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code returns `0` if both are length 0. You can see *almost* the same style in the [Wikibooks implementation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python); but the coder here  simply hasn't thought the code through.

You can simply change that second test to:

```
if not target:
    return 0
```

and not change the meaning.

The Wikibooks implementation tests *source* however:

```
if not source:
    return len(target)
```

which makes much more sense.

The function would do more work after that line; it is merely a boundaries check. With the check gone, the algorithm would still work just less efficiently; the Wikibooks version would produce a series of 1-element lists ranging from `[1]` through to `[len(target)]` then return that last element; so `len(target)`.

Comment: `if not target: return len(source)`. Returning `0` if `len(target)` is `0` is wrong.

Comment: @Matthias: no, because the  line before *already determined that source is the same length or shorter*

Comment: Oh, I mixed up `<` and `>`in my head.

Comment: To add on, wouldn't it be neater to test if both strings are actually equal? If yes, return 0. Instead of testing if both are length 0

Comment: @georg: Right. That case has to be covered later in the code.

Comment: @MaTaKazer: but then you are looping over the full strings anyway. Sure, it is masked by Python C code, but from an algorithm POV that's doing the work twice.

Comment: @MaTaKazer Even better: find the longest common prefix of the two strings, then the longest common suffix. If the strings are equal, the algorithm finishes immediately after. If they're not equal but share common prefixes or suffixes, the quadratic-time part gets smaller inputs.